# calculate time difference between hours / NaN value

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to calculate the difference between times.

```
['08:30', '09:30']  // End - Start should = 60 min
```

Here is what I have tried,

```
let timeEnd = moment(event.end).format('HH:mm');
let timeStart = moment(event.start).format('HH:mm');
```

However, I keep getting ***NaN***

```
console.log(Number(timeEnd) - Number(timeStart));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why are you trying to convert a time string to a number? moment has functions for getting time differences.

Comment: @DanielA.White I didn't know that moment has time difference function : /

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: If you didn't use moment, but a plain Date object, this approach would work, as demonstrated by the documentation of the Number() constructor. But since a date object created by moment.js isn't the same as a native Date object, the Number() constructor can't call the correct methods to transform the Date into  miliseconds. Just stick to using the moment API, it basically has everything.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yv2fgc02/